# Ansible import_role tags and sub tasks

Tags: ansible

I am trying to understand how tags are passed in ansible and I am using this test playbook

local.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
   - name: test role
     import_role: 
       name: test
     tags: test
```

roles/test/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: test role task
  include_tasks: 
    file: test_task.yml
```

roles/test/tasks/test_task.yml

```
- debug: msg="test_task"
```

From my understanding, the import_role will cause the test tag to be applied to all the tasks of that role. And that the include_tasks will stop tags from being passed onto the tasks that are being included.

But this is what I get as output

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [test : test role task] ******************************************************************************************************************
included: /home/fleetscut/temp/roles/test/tasks/test_task.yml for localhost

TASK [test : debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "test_task"
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The include is run as expected because it inherits the test tag from the parent. However what I don't understand is why the tasks from inside the include are run. They should not inherit the test tag and therefore should be skipped.

I have tried to include a tag on the sub task incase there was some default action on untagged tasks, but still the same outcome.

Is my understanding of tag inheritance incorrect? Or does a roles tags get passed down to sub tasks regardless of if they were included or imported?

Comment: I can reproduce, but, from what I read in the documentation, they do discourage you to have a mix of `import_*` and `include_*`: [_If you want tag inheritance, you probably want to use imports. However, using both includes and imports in a single playbook can lead to difficult-to-diagnose bugs_](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#tag-inheritance-for-includes-blocks-and-the-apply-keyword).

Comment: It's not documented: ``"implicit" block gets inserted in between the import_role and the tasks ... Due to inheritance, the tags is applied to the block. Then the include_tasks also inherits the test tag, and because we allow inheritance of tags from static parents, the tasks within test_task.yml also inherit the test tag from the block.`` See [#46662](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/46662#issuecomment-428274862).

Comment: I added the tag ``ansible-undocumented``. The problem is not described in [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/). Feel free to remove the tag if you find the problem will have been described.